Total 3 digit nos. that can be formed (without repetition) that are divisible by 5
I am trying to compute the total number of $3$-digit numbers. That can be formed, without repeating digits, that are divisible by $5$.
So there are two cases:

The number ends in $0$
The number ends in $5$.

For the first case, if 0 is fixed in the unit place, then any $9$ numbers can be fixed in the tenth place, and the remaining $8$ can be fixed in the hundredth place, giving us a count of $9 \times 8 = 72$.
For the second case, we fix $5$ in the unit place. Now, here is my confusion. If we first fill the hundredth place, we have $8$ choices ($0$ and $5$ can't be used), and in the tenth place, we also have $8$ choices giving us $8 \times 8 = 64$ total such numbers. However, if we fill the tenth place, first we have $9$ choices (only $5$ can't be used as it is fixed), and in the hundredth place, we are left with $7$ choices ($0, 5$, and the number used in tenth place can't be used) giving us $7 \times 9 = 63$ total such numbers.
So, in the second case, for the numbers ending in $5$, if we fill from left to right, we get $64$, and if we fill from right to left, we get $63$. I know the correct answer is $64$, but why is $63$ incorrect?

3 digit nos. which cannot have 0 in the hundredth place.

In general, it is a good idea to handle the most restrictive conditions first so that you avoid handling special cases such as the one true blue anil pointed out.

To answer your specific query about what is wrong with your second method, you are forgetting that if $0$ is the middle digit, we get 8 available digits for the hundreth place,
thus $(8\times7) + (1\times8) = 64$, as before
In problems of this sort, therefore, you need to carefully choose the order in which digits are to be placed so as to give the simplest computation

Thanks, I guess it answers my confusion.

Glad to be of help ! $;;$ :)

Case I: The number ends with a $0$
You have $2$ places left,in the tenth place you can have $9$ options and in the hundredth place you have $8$ options. Giving you total $8 \times 9 = 72$ combinations
Case II: The number ends with $5$
I will suggest you to take solve it here similiar to how we did in Case I and then subtract the possibility of having zero in the hundredth place
In the tenth place you have $9$ options and in the hundredth place you have $8$ options, so $8 \times 9 = 72$, we can't have a $0$ in the hundredth place, so we will subtract that with $72$, having $0$ in the hundredth place and $5$ in the units place gives $8$ combinations. So finally we have $72-8 = 64$
Total combinations : $72 + 64 = 136$
